# Flutter android licenses acceptance error

Tags: java, android, flutter

I am trying to accept flutter android licenses using `flutter doctor --android-licenses` but I keep getting the error in the image below.

[image]

I have combed the internet for about 2 days but not getting a workaround. Any help to solving this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to install android commandline tools from the sdk manager. Then it will not cause the error again:

You can install and update each package using Android Studio's SDK Manager or the SDK manager command-line tool. All of the packages are downloaded into your Android SDK directory, which you can locate as follows:

[image: 1. In Android Studio, click File > Project Structure. 2. Select SDK Location in the left pane. The path is shown under Android SDK location.]

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are probably using a new version of JDK. Building Android applications require JDK version 8 and only 8.
Try removing current JDK from your environment variables (path and JAVA_HOME) and installing JDK 8 instead. Remember to add JDK 8 to both your environment variables path and as JAVA_HOME.
This will probably fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks ARK1375, your suggestion solved part of my problem. The second part of the error is now gone but the first part still remains.

Comment: I'll look it up, meanwhile try this. Find your Android SDK folder (for me _c:\users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk_), open it in a cmd and move to _Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/_ then try running `./sdkmanager --licenses
` this command and see what happens.